# Change Crystal Report PrintDate Field to SqlServer Date

Tags: crystal-reports

I have Server, and a Client. I want to display Server Date in Crystal report Print field instead of local date of Client. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You would have to return the server date from the SQL Server to your Crystal Report and replace the PrintDate field with your new field.

e.g

**SQL**

```
Select Col1,
Col2,
...
GetDate() as 'ServerDateTime'

From dbo.MyTable
```

Replace `{PrintDate}` in the Crystal Report with `{ServerDateTime}` from the list of Database Fields

Comment: +1 Note that if the main dataset returns no records, the ServerDateTime will be unpopulated. One way around this would be to retrieve the ServerDateTime separately, in a subreport, although this is overkill where the report can be expected to return data

Comment: @Mark - Yes this is true.  Another way would be to check in the SQL that at least one row is returned. If it isn't then you could return a row of `null` values along with the Server date time.