# What to replace in Crystal Report Programmatically?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, vb6-migration

I have a line of code to set the Report.PrintDate in VB6.How can we replace this line for CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument ? In VB6 we have it is the inbuilt property for CRAXDRT.Report.

So can any once help me regarding this ?

Comment: you want to show the print date in the report itself?

Comment: Yes but I want to set the print date Programmatically

Answer (score 2):

if you want to show the current Date/Time of the printed report, you can use the built in `Special Fields` within the report designer . From your comment I understand you want to set that programatically. Then you need to create a Parameter and set it from code.

[image]

You can watch this [DEMO](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vqqeVWJcoag) to get to know how to create parameters. [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9197214/799558) would show you how to pass the parameter from code.

Comment: Yes , Is there any property in CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument to set the PrintDate Programmatically?

Comment: @JaiGanesh See my updated answer, if you have any questions please ask.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any possibility to set Programmatically>  I found this link http://scn.sap.com/thread/1472366

Comment: @JaiGanesh I'm afraid the answer given in the link is incorrect, the PrintDate is a special field and can't be changed. Whats the problem with using parameters?

Comment: @JaiGanesh See [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491487/change-crystal-report-printdate-field-to-sqlserver-date) question for example , if the date you are trying to set is coming from a database field, then you don't even need to set that from code, just use the bound field in the designer.